# initially empty img with fixed width, initial height, and auto height upon src

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how to achieve the following.

I have an `img` tag which has a given `width`, and initially contains no `src`. It also has a 2px black border.

I would like to give it an initial height that I can specify, but which switches to `height:auto` once a `src` is assigned (via a file `input`).

Is this possible using only html & css?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you can. The JavaScript would be really easy to do though.

Comment: maybe by using min-height? it will work find if you make sure min-height will always be smaller or equal to the final height

Comment: Could you show the code that takes the input and updates the img src? The change of sizing from a fixed height to auto can be done by CSS but not the placing of the input filename as the img src.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CSS will adjust the height of the containing div depending whether the img element has a src set or not.

It starts by setting the img to the width and height required. Then if there is a src attribute it changes height to auto. Then if the src attribute is empty it sets the height to the required default.

```css
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  background: pink;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}

img[src] {
  height: auto;
  border: solid 2px black;
}

img[src=""] {
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<p>The container div is pink</p>
<p>There is no src in the img element</p>
<div class="container">
  <img/>
</div>
<p>src in img element is set</p>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300" />
</div>
<p>There is an empty src in img element</p>
<div class="container">
  <img src="" />
</div>
```

The container div has been given a bit of padding so it can be seen behind the img just for this demo.